# Which place was this video shot in?

Tags: identify-this, beaches, locate-this

I don't think we have a *Google Video Search* and I am very curious about this:

Which city is depicted in [this video](https://www.facebook.com/1405190716450837/videos/1646213919015181/)?

[image]

Someone said Gran Canaria, others said Croatia, but I don't think it's either of them. Could someone help?

Comment: Clues: vegetation, water colour, people's skin colour, and most importantly: the skyline of the mountains in the background.  The video doesn't add anything that a still showing those four clues does.  You could add a still as an image to this question.

Comment: Definitely not Croatia.

Comment: You can message the owners of that FB page - why not ask them?

Answer (score 6):

The peak in the background is Mount Otemanu on the island of Bora Bora in French Polynesia. I am not 100% sure exactly where the video was shot, but it could be from the laguna of the St. Regis Bora Bora resort, at least somewhere around [this image](https://www.google.de/maps/@-16.4855709,-151.6941681,3a,90y,174.98h,89.76t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-1o8_gO9CBwo%2FVgsE0rjnVmI%2FAAAAAAAAIF0%2FutMCSXMvtTcEibOFJMc7CwLaPYVUop79QCJkC!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh6.googleusercontent.com%2F-1o8_gO9CBwo%2FVgsE0rjnVmI%2FAAAAAAAAIF0%2FutMCSXMvtTcEibOFJMc7CwLaPYVUop79QCJkC%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya239.52097-ro0-fo100%2F!7i8704!8i2804) from Google Maps.

Comment: So this is definitely Bora Bora? Wow. Nice! I'll sort the hotel out haha. Thanks man!

Comment: The French definitely supports that. And I only saw such jagged peaks in Tahiti and the Marquesas